# Regarding image texture loading in three js

Tags: three.js

I want to load an image on to a plane.But I am having a problem in loading.So,here I am getting the image like this.

```
var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Silk.png');
        var Silk = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(15,15),new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:texture,color:'skyblue'}));
        scene.add(Silk);
        Silk.position.z = -2;
```

[And This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak3xK.png)

[I want only the image not the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdKqa.png)

How can I do that?

Comment: It does exactly what it have to. If you are using perspective camera, plane is scaled in distance. You can use orthographic camera. If you want to only use as a non active background, use DOM behind scene without THREE, or you can put a second scene with another orthographic camera and render it first each frame.  Or use skybox, but you will need sophisticated texture https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Skybox.html

Comment: Try `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({... transparent:true})`

Comment: @pailhead it's not working